# hide and show the div depending on clicking button (jquery)

Tags: jquery

How can i hide and show a content depending on clicking to button? I try do it but it doesn't work and i have no clue what's wrong. Can you help me?

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


 <div id="list" >

    <input id="button" type="button" value="Show Status"   onclick="ShowHide()" />
</div>


<div id="content2" style="display:none" >
    <img src="http://kobylnica.pl/pic/item,69,1,x.jpg" alt="Tekst alternatywny" />
    Miejsce na wyświetlenie filmiku i opisu trasy
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHide(){
            if ($("#content2").css('display') == 'none'){
            $("#content2").show();
            $("#button").val("Hide");
        }
        else{
            $("#content2").hide();
            $("#button").val("Show Status");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/dTN9h/1/

Comment: @Barmar - Let me pimp that for you -> **http://jsfiddle.net/dTN9h/3/**

Comment: Maybe it's time to update your jQuery, you're using a three year old version of jQuery.

Comment: In fact the problem was too old version of jQuery - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code with :

```
<div id="list" >
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Show Status" onclick="$('#content2').toggle(); ($(this).val() == 'Hide')?$(this).val('Show Status'):$(this).val('Hide')" />
</div>
```

Comment: What about the button text? Inline jQuery always make me shudder !

Comment: That doesn't change the label on the button from `Hide` to `Show`.

Comment: It change the text now

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="list">
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Show Status" onclick="ShowHide()" />
</div>
<div id="content2" style="display:none">
    <img src="http://kobylnica.pl/pic/item,69,1,x.jpg" alt="Tekst alternatywny" />Miejsce na wyświetlenie filmiku i opisu trasy</div>
<script>
function ShowHide(){
    $("#content2").toggle();
    $("#button").val(function(_,t) { return t == "Hide" ? 'Show Status' : "Hide"; });
}
</script>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dTN9h/4/